# Setting the starting number of a Jupyter notebook heading

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Using # in a markdown cell in jupyter notebook will start the numbering from 1. How do I start the numbering from another number, eg. like 3, so that the first heading has the starting number of 3 instead of 1?

I tried to place {} behing the hashtag, eg. #{3} and other combinations #(3), but that did not produce the required output.

I partly solved the problem by just adding a number of dummy chapters and then a new page and not printing the first page. This is a less elegant solution.
The code used in a markdown cell:

```
# Dummy text 1
# Dummy text 2
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
```